# React Native - change component style by key

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I know that in `html` and `javascript` are able to change it own `css` style by `id` and `class` , in react native, how to set / change the component style. I have `map` a list of component, and each of them have set a `key` value. When I call a function, I would like to change one of the component style.

**eg: change the `key` is 2 component style**

```
_RenderSpecialItem(){
  return this.state.speciallist.map((item, i)=>{
    return(
      <SpecialItem 
        key={i}
      />
    );
  });
}

_ChangeStyle(){
  //do something
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use [Direct Manipulation](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/direct-manipulation.html) but it's not a good practice, for more please read

> Direct manipulation will not be a tool that you reach for frequently; you will typically only be using it for creating continuous animations to avoid the overhead of rendering the component ...

in the link. Otherwise, you should you set state in component and change state to update the style

e.g.

first set ref to the component :

```
<SpecialItem 
    key={i}
    ref={(thisItem) => this[`item-${i}`] = thisItem}
/>
```

then setNativeProps :

```
_ChangeStyle() {
    this['item-2'].setNativeProps({style: {/* your style here */}});
}
```

full example

```
export default class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        speciallist: ['aaa', 'bbb', 'ccc']
    }
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this['text-0'].setNativeProps({style: {fontSize: "10"}});
    this['text-1'].setNativeProps({style: {fontSize: "20"}});
    this['text-2'].setNativeProps({style: {fontSize: "30"}});
  }

  render() {

    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        {
          this.state.speciallist.map((item, i)=>(
            <Text
              key={`text-${i}`}
              ref={(thisItem) => this[`text-${i}`] = thisItem}
            >
              {item}
            </Text>
          ))
        }
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: getting this error `Cannot read property 'setNativeProps' of undefined`

Comment: few things... have you use bind the function to the class and is the function run after rendering? I've updated a full example... you can check the `setNativeProps` in componentDidMount to change the style after rendering

Comment: stil getting `Cannot read property 'setNativeProps' of undefined`

Comment: hi, i try follow your changestyle function ,it gave me this error `TypeError: _this[("item-2")].setNativeProps is not a function`

Comment: You're getting undefined most likely because `componentDidMount()` is called before `.map` has had time to execute. Adding a timer may help.